# problem with sql query string

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I'm having a problem displaying a sum total, getting the error

```
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

The query I am using is as follows;

```
    SELECT     
SUM(a_count) AS total

FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        TOP (100) PERCENT CONVERT(varchar, dt_created, 106) AS dt_created, 
        COUNT(*) AS a_count        
    FROM
        fulf AS a
    WHERE
        (source = '10wnt47') 
        AND (dt_created >= '01 jan 2011') 
        AND (dt_created <= '11 apr 2011')
    GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar, dt_created, 106)
    ) 
AS b
```

The strange thing is that this query works perfectly when simply quering the database, but when trying to use it within an aspx page it seems to fall over.  I am already using the query (without the sum being generated) and it works fine.  It's probably something obvious that I am missing but I can't see it...

The stack trace is as follows...

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '('.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +1950890
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4846875
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2392
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() +33
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +83
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +297
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +954
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +32
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +141
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() +89
   _Default.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\amayberry\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\chart_test\iframe2.aspx.vb:95
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
```

The code im using to build and execute the query is as follows.

```
Using myConnection As New SqlConnection
            myConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("VisitScotlandConnectionString").ConnectionString

            Dim mySelect As New SqlCommand
            mySelect.Connection = myConnection
            mySelect.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(a_count) AS total FROM (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT CONVERT(varchar, dt_created, 106) AS dt_created, COUNT(*) AS a_count FROM fulf AS a WHERE (source = '10wnt47') AND (dt_created >= '01 jan 2011') AND (dt_created <= '11 apr 2011') GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar, dt_created, 106)) AS b"
            myConnection.Open()
            Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = mySelect.ExecuteReader()

            If myReader.Read() Then
                total = myReader("total").ToString()
                Response.Write(total)
            End If

            myReader.Close()
            myConnection.Close()
        End Using
```

It's fairly straightforward and is fired when a button on a page is clicked (after getting variables from the user (which I have replaced for illustration purposes)

Comment: did you try running it this way, using constants rather than the dynamic user variables and you get the same error?

Comment: I did, this was one of the first things i tried to rule out that it was the variables causing the issue, same error with constraints or variables

Comment: sorry. i don't know any reason why the query would work being run on its own and not work when calling the identical query in asp.net. i have never had this problem.

Comment: thanks for yuor help up until now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i ended up scrapping that and re-writing the code and it seemed to work fine with this version of code:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS Total FROM dbo.fulf 
WHERE
        (source = '" & vSource & "') 
    AND 
        (dt_created >= '" & Format(vStartDate, "dd MMM yyyy") & "') 
    AND 
        (dt_created <= '" & Format(vEndDate, "dd MMM yyyy") & "') 
ORDER BY 
    Total DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

the final `order by` seems to be in a funny place.  it is probably not required.

Comment: i've tried removing this (it is redundant from a previous query and so not required) but getting the error Incorrect syntax near '('. Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'a_1'.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to remove the 'AS' clauses that you put after the table names. So they should be (note, I replaced some of your variable names):

```
SELECT SUM(TotalCount) AS total 
FROM  
    (
        SELECT 
            TOP (100) PERCENT CONVERT(varchar, dt_created, 106) AS dt_created, 
            cnt AS TotalCount 
        FROM  
            (
                SELECT 
                    CONVERT(varchar, dt_created, 106) AS dt_created, 
                    COUNT(*) AS cnt 
                FROM 
                    dbo.fulf a  
                WHERE 
                    (source = 'thing') 
                    AND (dt_created >= 'date') 
                    AND (dt_created <= 'date')  
                GROUP BY 
                    CONVERT(varchar, dt_created, 106)
            ) a_1 
        ORDER BY 
            CONVERT(datetime, dt_created, 106)
    ) b
```

Comment: could also be a problem that you are using "count" as an identifier since "count" is a reserved word. you should probably change it.

Comment: Thanks for your help up to now, I am now getting the following error Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '('.
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'a_1'.

Comment: have you tried putting a breakpoint in the code after the query is stored in a variable but before it is executed to verify the variable has what you expect? Because the query works for you outside of the code, but not in the code, the likely problem is with the dynamic variables you are loading.

Comment: Yes, i've already thought this could be causing the problem but the variables are being stored OK prior to the query being executed.  the error is flagged as soon as I try to execute the sql query

Comment: interestingly, creating a 'new query' (i am developing using VWD2008 Exp) will always add in the 'AS' keyword upon execution when i try testing the query directly against the database altho i have tested both versions in SQL Server Exp. management studio and either query with or without 'as' will return successfully...i'm completely at a loss as to why the error is being thrown...

Comment: can you update the question with your changes to the query so that we can see what you have now? is the middle tier query even needed since you are just selecting a total?

Comment: you're right, the middle tier can be deleted as it's not needed - I've updated the query in the initail question to show what I am now working with - the error being returned is Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: at this point, i don't see a problem. i even verified it on my side, and i am able to execute the query successfully on a db with similar columns. without anyone else noticing the problem, i would suggest adding the code you use to build and execute the query to the question because the problem may be likely coming from that code.

Comment: I've added the build and execute code in my question but I don't see anything obvious that would throw an error?